# Kill Process Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu

I wish to use command line ( bash ) to find and kill a process.
How do I search for a known (VLC ) process and how do I kill it ?

Guy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to other suggestions you can use `xkill`, in a terminal type `xkill` then click on your desired window (VLC, or any other). it will kill it.

You can also combine `kill` and `pidof`:

```
kill $(pidof -s vlc)
```

or use killall:

```
killall vlc
```

which kill all instances.

Answer (score 3):

Fist type

```
pidof vlc
```

after

```
kill -9  pid
```

or

```
pkill pid
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the process with `pgrep`, kill it with `pkill`. Read `man pgrep` (the same `man` page documents `pkill`)